# vba how to check if filter gives results (visible property inclueds header)

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am running the following code in order to filter and then check if the filter gave results:

```
Sub filter()
    Dim field1Col As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim typeRange As Range

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    field1Col = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Col1", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=field1Col, Criteria1:="c"

    On Error Resume Next
        Set typeRange = tbl.ListColumns("col1").Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If typeRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "no filtered values"
    Else
        Debug.Print typeRange.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

My Criteria is "C". When there are no "C" values, the visible range is still not 'Nothing' because it includes the header. The above code will print the header of the column.

I would I check if after filtering there are no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
Set typeRange = tbl.ListColumns("col1").Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

with this line:

```
Set typeRange = tbl.ListColumns("col1").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

Assuming the filtered range was defined as:

```
Set rDATA = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
```

Then you'll need to resize the range with something like this:

```
With rDATA
    On Error Resume Next
    Set typeRange = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, what if my data is not in a table and I define my range to filter as: Sheet1.range("A1:A" & lastRow)? How would I check if I got results?